# How to calculate brightness from list of unsigned 8 bytes integer which represents an image in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, rasterizing

I wanted to calculate the brightness of an UintList image. The image I used are picked from my phone (Using image_picker plugin in flutter). I tried a for loop on every value of this list and did this:

```dart
int r = 0, b = 0, g = 0, count = 0;
for (int value in imageBytesList) {
  /// The red channel of this color in an 8 bit value.
  int red = (0x00ff0000 & value) >> 16;

  /// The blue channel of this color in an 8 bit value.
  int blue = (0x0000ff00 & value) >> 8;

  /// The green channel of this color in an 8 bit value.
  int green = (0x000000ff & value) >> 0;
  r += red;
  b += blue;
  g += green;
  count++;
}
double result = (r + b + g) / (count * 3);
```

I know that the *result* should represent a brightness level between 0 and 255, where 0 = totally black and 255 = totally bright. but, what I get are really weird values like 0.0016887266175341332. What calculation mistakes am I making? (I know my method is gravely wrong but I wasn't able to find a way).

The flutter image widget does convert this Uint8List from memory to an Image with correct height & width using `Image.memory()` constructor. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: you are not using ARBG values but encoded data (png, jpg whatever) - you need to convert it to a list of raw pixels first - you could try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Image-class.html for example

Comment: Is there a guide/reference from where I can learn about converting encoded data (from different formats) to raw pixels?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Decoder-class.html

Comment: I've checked flutter's image class and dart:ui's Image class. None gives the methods to convert to pixels or whatever as mentioned in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Image-class.html. What is this documentation referring to?

Comment: read the second paragraph: "Pixels are stored in 32-bit unsigned integers in #AARRGGBB format."

Comment: I get that but the instance method it suggests like toBytes()  or getPixels() isn't available on the sdk

Comment: why dont you simply read the whole second paragraph? after `"Pixels are stored in 32-bit unsigned integers in #AARRGGBB format."` they write how to get a list of those ARGB pixels

Comment: I read it, but I cannot use those methods in my application. Instance methods of Image class (widget) in flutter or dart:ui doesn't provide those methods. And I don't find other Image class anywhere

Comment: whats the output of `flutter --version` ?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0

Comment: as you can see here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Image-class.html the docs ar for `1.12.13+hotfix.5` (on the bottom of the page) - there is `image` library: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/image-library.html - all you need to do is to import it

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble. Thanks, I finally did it. I though those methods belonged to dart:ui.Image or flutter:wigets.Image. Importing as `import 'image/image.dart';` solved this issue as u suggested.